# Enviar por e-mail um código html digitado no textarea pelo php

Tags: php, html

O problema não acontece só nos e-mails, então por favor sem sugestões de phpmailer, pois estou com problema para apresentrar o texto formatado em html que foi digitado no textarea até mesmo na minha própria página.

Se eu coloco no php:

```
$html = "<p style='color:red;'>Mensagem:</p>".$_POST['mensagem'];
```

Então a palavra "Mensagem" quando chega no e-mail chega em vermelho, mas o que esta dentro do post (que seria um textarea) "mensagem" chega só texto, se eu colocasse lá dentro:

```
<p style='color:red;'>exemplo</p>
```

Irá aparecer apenas a palavra exemplo sem cor vermelha ao chegar o e-mail.

**Pelo meus testes, não é só no e-mail que ele não chega formatado o html, se eu mando apresentar na tela da minha página o que foi digitado no textarea, também não formata o html que ali foi digitado.**

Basicamente é isso o que esta ocorrendo no meu código, tudo que esta dentro do textarea não esta se transformando em html no e-mail, mas se eu digito o codigo html no meu php, ele vai, provavelmente é alguma forma de tratar o post do textarea que esta faltando.

Segue meu codigo quase inteiro a baixo (sem o formulário):

```
function enviar($metodo,$op) {
    if ($metodo=="Hospedagem") {

        $emailremetente = $_POST['emailremetente'];
        $array_domain=array("@oi.com.br","@gmail.com");
        foreach ($array_domain as $elemento) {
            $emailsender = str_replace("$elemento","@127.0.0.1",$emailremetente);
        }

        $nomeremetente = $_POST['nomeremetente'];
        $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];

        $array_destinatario = array();
        $array_destinatario = explode("\n",trim($_POST['emaildestinatario']));

        $message = opcao("$op");

        imprime_headers($array_destinatario,$nomeremetente,$emailsender,$emailremetente,$assunto);

        foreach($array_destinatario as $elemento) {

            $headers = headers($emailsender,$nomeremetente,$assunto);

            if (mail($elemento, $assunto, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers), "-r". $emailsender)){
                emailEnviado($elemento,$metodo,$nomeremetente);
            }else {
                emailFalhou($elemento,$metodo,$nomeremetente);
            }

        }
        ?><div class="imprime_msgSent">Terminou! Veja a mensagem que foi enviada:</div><?php
        echo "<div style='border:1px solid gray;padding:15px;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);margin-bottom:5px;'>$message</div>";
        echo "<div style='border:1px solid gray;padding:15px;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);margin-bottom:5px;color:black;'>".htmlentities($message)."</div>";
    }
}
function opcao($var) {
    if ($var=="template") {
        changeTemplate($_POST['nomeremetente'],$_POST['telefone'],$_POST['cnpj'],$_POST['site'],$_POST['assunto']);
        include("inc/htmlT.php");
        $message = $htmlT;
    }
    else if ($var=="textarea") {
        $_SESSION["mensagemHTML"] = $_POST["mensagem"];
        $message = "
                <div style='padding:5px;border:1px solid pink;color:yellow;background-color:blue;'>HtMl PeRsOnAlIzAdO Do <strong>bArUlHo</strong></div>
                <hr/>
                {$_SESSION['mensagemHTML']}
                ";
    }
    return $message;
}
function headers($emailsender,$nomeremetente,$assunto) {
    $headers   = array();
    $headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
    $headers[] = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    $headers[] = "From: {$emailsender}";
    $headers[] = "Reply-To: ".str_replace(" ","_",$nomeremetente)."<{$emailremetente}>";
    $headers[] = "Subject: {$assunto}";
    return $headers;
}
```

Tela do e-mail no formulário com código html para sair AMARELO:

[image: ENVIANDO]

Tela após enviado, pode perceber que ele não saiu da cor amarela, e no e-mail também não recebe nenhuma formatação de cor amarela por causa do style color yellow.

[image: ENVIADO]

Aqui mais a baixo é a imagem do recebimento no thunderbird (fica igual no gmail, etc)

[image: RECEBIDO NO EMAIL]

Comment: Qual o conteúdo de $_POST["mensagem"] após o envio do formulário post (imprima com var_dump($_POST["mensagem"])?

Comment: Você está exibindo isso dentro de um span?

Comment: vmartins, se eu dou vardump aparece assim:

string(51) "
insira texto html aqui

"

Comment: KhaosDoctor: Não, não coloco dentro de um span, por que deveria?